# Possible to make this SQL query faster?

Tags: mysql

Just curious if it's possible to make this query any faster? or if there is any other similar queries that would work better?

```sql
SELECT id,source FROM posts
WHERE id = ANY(SELECT image_id FROM `post_tags` WHERE tag_id = (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE tag = _utf8 '$TAG' collate utf8_bin))
  AND posts.exists = 'n'
ORDER BY posts.ratecount DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Without using the:

```sql
  AND posts.exists = 'n'
ORDER BY posts.ratecount
DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

It speeds up to query to usable levels, but somewhat need this for what I'm doing.

- Tags table has unique index for both 'tag' and 'id'.
- Tags has 83K rows.
- Post_tags has unique index for 'image_id', 'tag_id'. Also normal index for each.
- Post_tags has 471K rows.
- Posts has unique index for 'id'. Also normal index for 'exists' and 'ratecount'.
- Posts table has about 1.1M rows.

Comment: How much data is in table posts and post_tags? Do you have all necessary indices set?

Comment: Query plan shows what? Are the indices actually being used? Rewriting in terms of a normal join makes a difference? (Sometimes planners go wonk.) Table statistics are updated? Anyway, put all information in the original post. Also perhaps try on DBA. Voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: You should get some speed back if you can restructure it to use `JOIN` instead of sub-`SELECT`.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the `ORDER BY` as the culprit.

Comment: Would be nice if he posted the explain, chances are it may be resulting to a filesort.

Comment: What is your TAG table look like? Does it contain only ID and TAG fields? I would create a an unique index on `TAG(TAG, ID)` so the inner most query just searches an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working using a JOIN as someone suggested.

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_tags ON post_tags.image_id = posts.id
JOIN tags ON post_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.tag = _utf8 '$tag' collate utf8_bin
  AND posts.exists = 'n'
ORDER BY posts.ratecount DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

Reduced time taken from 22s > 0.26s.

Answer (score 0):

What is your TAG table look like? Does it contain only ID and TAG fields? I would create a an unique index on `TAG(TAG, ID)` so the inner most query just searches an index.

What about POST_TAGS table? Is it just a combination of TAG_ID and IMAGE_ID? Again, I would create an unique index on `POST_TAGS(IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID)`.

Just to note that order of fields in an index is important, and an index on `POST_TAGS(TAG_ID, IMAGE_ID)` differs much with an index on `POST_TAGS(IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID)` using in parsing plans.

And in the POSTS table having an unique index on `POSTS(ID, POSTS, RATEACCOUNT)` can help, (I know it is an redundant index, and make extra cost on INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, but it will help you in this query).

By the way, using a JOIN in the inner query may give you performance gain, just check it.

Comment: Tag table contains id/tag/tagcount. Already have a unique index for POST_TAGS(IMAGE_ID, TAG_ID).